# openCL Long Overflowing

Tags: opencl, integer-overflow

Before I start I am a C beginner and I am trying to do some openCL work which might have been a mistake. Below is my kernel code:

```
__kernel void collatz(__global int* in, __global int* out)
{
    uint id = get_global_id(0);
    unsigned long n = (unsigned long)id;
    uint count = 0;

    while (n > 1) { 
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n = n / 2; 
        } else { 
            if(n == 1572066143) {
                unsigned long test = n;
                printf("BEFORE - %lu\n", n);
                test = (3 * test) + 1; 
                printf("AFTER  - %lu\n", test);

                n = (3 * n) + 1; 
             } else {
                 n = (3 * n) + 1; 
            }

       }

       count = count + 1;
    }

    out[id] = count;

}
```

and the output:

```
BEFORE - 1572066143
AFTER  - 421231134
```

To me it looks like n is overflowing but I can't figure out why it is happening.

The interesting thing is if I create a new variable to store the same value as n then it seems to work correctly.

```
unsigned long test = 1572066143;
printf("BEFORE - %lu\n", test);
test = (3 * test) + 1; 
printf("AFTER  - %lu\n", test);
```

Output:

```
 BEFORE - 1572066143
 AFTER  - 4716198430
```

As I said I am a C beginner so I could be doing something very stupid! Any help would be appreciated as I have been pulling my hair out for hours now!

Thanks,
Stephen

**Update:**

Here is my host code in case I am doing something stupid on that end:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    /*Step1: Getting platforms and choose an available one.*/
    cl_uint numPlatforms;   //the NO. of platforms
    cl_platform_id platform = NULL; //the chosen platform
    cl_int  status = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);

    cl_platform_id* platforms = (cl_platform_id*)malloc(numPlatforms*   sizeof(cl_platform_id));
    status = clGetPlatformIDs(numPlatforms, platforms, NULL);
    platform = platforms[0];
    free(platforms);

    /*Step 2:Query the platform and choose the first GPU device if has one.*/
    cl_device_id        *devices;
    devices = (cl_device_id*)malloc(1 * sizeof(cl_device_id));
    clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, devices, NULL);

    /*Step 3: Create context.*/
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, devices, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    /*Step 4: Creating command queue associate with the context.*/
    cl_command_queue commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, devices[0], 0, NULL);

    /*Step 5: Create program object */
    const char *filename = "HelloWorld_Kernel.cl";
    std::string sourceStr;
    status = convertToString(filename, sourceStr);
    const char *source = sourceStr.c_str();
    size_t sourceSize[] = { strlen(source) };
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, &source, sourceSize, NULL);

    status = clBuildProgram(program, 1, devices, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    /*Step 7: Initial input,output for the host and create memory objects for the kernel*/
    cl_ulong max = 2000000;
    cl_ulong *numbers = NULL;
    numbers = new cl_ulong[max];
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        numbers[i] = i;
    }

    int *output = (int*)malloc(sizeof(cl_ulong) * max);

    cl_mem inputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, max * sizeof(cl_ulong), (void *)numbers, NULL);
    cl_mem outputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, max * sizeof(cl_ulong), NULL, NULL);

    /*Step 8: Create kernel object */
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "collatz", NULL);

    /*Step 9: Sets Kernel arguments.*/
    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&inputBuffer);


    // Determine the size of the log
    size_t log_size;
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, devices[0], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &log_size);

    // Allocate memory for the log
    char *log = (char *)malloc(log_size);

    // Get the log
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, devices[0], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, log_size, log, NULL);

    // Print the log
    printf("%s\n", log);


    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&outputBuffer);

    /*Step 10: Running the kernel.*/
    size_t global_work_size[] = { max };
    status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 1, NULL, global_work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

   /*Step 11: Read the data put back to host memory.*/
   status = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, outputBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, max * sizeof(cl_ulong), output, 0, NULL, NULL);


return SUCCESS;
```

}

Comment: Could just be a compiler bug, I get the right results when I run the same kernel on my own machine. Which OpenCL platform and device are you using? Have you tried a different one?

Comment: Thanks for the response and trying it out on your end. I am using the AMD SDK. I have tried it on both my Intel Integrated Graphics as well as my AMD graphics card 280x but both produce the wrong results. I might try positing the same question on the AMD developer forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of the issue.

I was running the code on my Intel HD Graphics 4600 chip and it was producing the strange behaviour shown in the original question. I switched to using my AMD card and then it started working as expected!

Very strange. Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0):

Host side and device size values have different sizes. In host, `long` can vary from 32 to 64bits, depending on the platform. In device, `long` refers to 64bits only.

`printf()` function, as defined in C says that `%ld` is to print long (host side long) numbers. You are using printf in a kernel, so.... It could be that the C-like parser is used, therefore printing the variable as a 32bits long.

Can you try printing it as `%lld` or as a floating point?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response I tried using %lld but get the same result.

Comment: Could it be that you are miss-interpreting the printf output? Workitems don't run in order, so the print can be of any thread. Mybe you are just looking at the after of a thread and the before of another. Does overflow happen with all the cases or just that one? Can you add an id to it? `printf("%u BEFORE - %lu\n", id, test);`